# MaterialApp just started to behave weird creating screens I have not clicked on

Tags: flutter

My MaterialApp started to behave strange today. The TournamnetScreen is created twice when I click on the admin tab.

What could possible cause this? I upgraded flutter yesterday. (stable channel)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

debugPrint("Starting Chess Champion");

return MaterialApp(
  theme: new ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey
  ),
  home: DefaultTabController(
    length: 5,
    child:
    Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Chess Champion', style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 30.0)),
        bottom: TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(AntDesign.table)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Octicons.versions)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(MaterialCommunityIcons.podium)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Octicons.tools)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          HomeScreen(title: 'Home',),
          DataTableScreen(),
          ChangelogScreen(),
          TeamTournamentScreen(),
          AdminScreen(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Admin widget here ..

```
class AdminScreen extends StatelessWidget {
final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Admin')),
  body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _createTour2,
          child: new Text('Create a tournament2'),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _readTour,
          child: new Text('Read a tournament'),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _deleteTour,
          child: new Text('Delete a tournament'),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _setTourLevel,
          child: new Text('Set level in all Tournaments'),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _listTours,
          child: new Text('List Tournaments'),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _listTour2s,
          child: new Text('List Tournament2s '),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _deleteDuplicatedTours,
          child: new Text('Delete Duplicated Tournaments'),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _scrapeAllsvenskan,
          child: new Text('Scrape Allsvenskan'),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _listClubs,
          child: new Text('List Clubs'),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _updateTour,
          child: new Text('Update a Tournament'),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _deleteDuplicatClubs,
          child: new Text('Remove duplicate Clubs'),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _dbCounts,
          child: new Text('Database Counts'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }),
);
}
```

Comment: can you post your code for AdminScreen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be to the fact that I accidentically created two MaterialApp's.